# How to show “next” and “previous” buttons on an image?

Tags: html, css

I've seen some images that have navigation - next and previous. I'm trying to replicate that navigation, but probably I'm making a mistake somewhere...

I added two navigation circles, but I'm having a hard time putting the "previous" and "next" triangles inside the circles...

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.screen-reader-text {
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  position: absolute !important;
}

.post-navigation span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4.5rem;
  height: 4.5rem;
  background-color: #333;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 0.25rem solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

.nav-previous,
.nav-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 37.5%;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.nav-previous,
.nav-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 37.5%;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.nav-previous {
  left: -1rem;
}

.nav-next {
  right: -1rem;
}

.post-navigation span::before,
.post-navigation span::after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-size: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.post-navigation span::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,50 80,100 80,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.post-navigation span::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='100,50 20,100 20,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="photo-template-author">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 photo--section--image">
        <div class="photo-video-box-shadow">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <nav class="navigation post-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="Post navigation">
              <h2 class="screen-reader-text">Post navigation</h2>
              <div class="nav-links">
                <div class="nav-previous"><a href="#" rel="prev">
                    <div class="nav-text"><span><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Previous</span> </div>
                  </a></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><a href="#" rel="next">
                    <div class="nav-text"><span>Next <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span> </div>
                  </a></div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Ctv1m-63Q7Q/TozUCb70gQI/AAAAAAAAAfw/UQk-nUN3NHM/s1600/beautiful+nature+scenery-1.jpg" alt="featured-image" class="featured-img img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

[Sample image with Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ4h9.png)

Comment: Dear Dalv try this code that is written below i hope this will help you thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `javascript` if your data comming from database you can loop on images.

```js
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    
    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
    
    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    
    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
```

```css
    * {box-sizing:border-box}
    
    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
      max-width: 1000px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    /* Hide the images by default */
    .mySlides {
      display: none;
    }
    
    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: -22px;
      padding: 16px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: 0.6s ease;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }
    
    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }
    
    /* Caption text */
    .text {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 8px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
    .numbertext {
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
    .dot {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }
    
    .active, .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }
    
    /* Fading animation */
    .fade {
      -webkit-animation-name: fade;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
      from {opacity: .4}
      to {opacity: 1}
    }
    
    @keyframes fade {
      from {opacity: .4}
      to {opacity: 1}
    }
```

```html
     <!-- Slideshow container -->
    <div class="slideshow-container">
    
      <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="https://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/394230.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
      </div>
    
      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    
    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
```

I hope this will help you. Try this; if not I will suggest you another solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set Font Awesome element as a button in your code you need to use

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
```